# How to use jmap remotelly without SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, jmx, remote-debugging

I've configured my linux remote machine (with JRE 1.7) to execute the java application with the necessary properties for jmx:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5005 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-jar myapplication.jar
```

Now in my windows local machine (where I have JDK 1.7) I want to use the tool jmap, for example to print the histogram:

`jmap -histo 10.218.72.227:5005`

But it's faling with the following error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Attaching to remote server 10.218.72.227:5005, please wait...
Error attaching to remote server: java.rmi.NotBoundException: Not bound: "SARemoteDebugger" (only bound name is "jmxrmi")
```

The weird thing is that I can connect using the jconsole successfully, but first it prompts me with a message to Retry the connection insecurely (without SSL):

[image]

Therefore, it seems like it should be some sort-of a flag for jmap in order to work, do you know how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Following the man page of [jsadebugd - Serviceability Agent Debug Daemon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jsadebugd.html) 
you need first to attach it to your process to be able to use `jmap` remotely.

The below steps show how it works.

The used Java version for all java processes (local and remote).

> java version "1.7.0_80"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

**execute on remote host**

1. start your application
   `java -jar myapplication.jar`
2. start the `rmiregistry`
   `rmiregistry -J-Xbootclasspath/p:$JAVA_HOME/lib/sajdi.jar &`
3. get the PID of your application using `jps` (e.g.12345)
4. attach the debug demon to your application
   `jsadebugd 12345 42`

**execute on local host**

1. execute `jmap`
   `jmap -heap 42@10.218.72.227`

**output on local host**

```
Attaching to remote server 42@10.218.72.227, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.80-b11
Iterating over heap. This may take a while...
Object Histogram:

num       #instances    #bytes  Class description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1:      5575    527488  * ConstMethodKlass
2:      5575    493168  * MethodKlass
...
```

Additional notes: The man page states `This utility is unsupported and may or may not be available in future versions of the JDK`.

Maybe running jmap on the remote machine (e.g. via ssh) would be a better approach.